# What is the fastest way to render an html table?

Tags: html, performance, html-table, rendering

I have seen comments on using [`table-layout: fixed`](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_tab_table-layout.asp).  I have seen comments on defining col widths upfront and also lots of comments on avoiding table especially nested tables and use some CSS solution instead of tables.

Is there an agreed documented solution for rendering an html table as fast as possible?
Also, if there is an alternative that is faster that would be great as well.

Comment: If you want to know how to *render* HTML tables as fast as possible, ask Opera: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/browserSpeed.html#winspeed. From your first paragraph I assume you want to know how to *write* your HTML so that older browsers without reflow can render a table with partial data quickly which is a slightly different thing. What browsers are you targetting?

Comment: I wonder what do you mean by "fast"? Are you referring to efficiency in terms of code logic (complexity), or how to do that client side without latency which may visually glitch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say don't sweat it, tables will render fine across all browsers, and speed is not an issue. That being said, use them for tabular data, if it's just for layout stick to divs.